# How to access document fields using document id in Cloud FireStore?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a

```
Querysnapshot snapshot
```

I can supply an index and access the fields of the document perfectly like:

```
snapshot.data!.docs[index]
```

However, I want to access the field of document 'thisParticularDocument' which is the id (name) of the document in Cloud Firestore.

I want to use

```
snapshot.data!.docs[thisParticularDocument]
```

but that doesn't work because you can only supply an index to *docs*.

I want a solution that preferably involves no async await.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the data of a document with a specific id without making a new async request by finding it like this:

```
   snapshot.data!.docs.firstWhere((doc) => doc.id == "the document Id").data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

this will get you the specific document from the `QuerySnapshot`.

Answer (score 1):

when you a get a `QuerySnapshot` then you get all all documents of it including references and data.

so you can get a specific document as you say like this:

```
snapshot.data!.docs[index]
```

and you can get the data of document like this:

```
snapshot.data!.docs[index].data() as Map<String, dynamic>
```

then you can get the specific field inside of it like this:

```
(snapshot.data!.docs[index].data() as Map<String, dynamic>)["thisParticularDocument"]
```

that's it the value of that field will be returned fine if it exists.

Comment: Thanks. However, the point is that I don't want to use any 'index' integer number to access the document. I want to provide the document name, for convenience this is called "thisParticularDocument", and then access the fields of that document.

Comment: do you mean you want to get just one document with the specific thisParticularDocument uid ?

Comment: Yes, if I use doc(thisParticularDocument).get() it will be a future and i cant make my widget async unfortunately and thus that wont be a solution

Comment: does my other answer fit your case?

Comment: Fantastic! It works flawlessly, thanks!